# Redirect two or more Powershell streams other than output stream to the same file

Tags: powershell, stream, io-redirection

In Powershell, we can combine the standard output stream with any other stream and then redirect (write) the result to the same file.

Examples:

```
Powershell -File "C:\myscript.ps1" 2>&1> "C:\log.txt"  
Powershell -File "C:\myscript.ps1" 3>&2>&1> "C:\log.txt"
```

Suppose I use *Write-Error* and *Write-Warning* statements in myscript.ps1 and I want to write only the errors and the warnings to the same file.

Note: if I am not mistaken, 1 is the output stream, 2 is the error stream and 3 the warning stream.

My first logical try was then to use *3>&2>* - if combining 1 and 2 works, why would not 3 and 2 ? See below:

```
Powershell -File "C:\myscript.ps1" 3>&2> "C:\log.txt"
```

However, *3>&2>* does not work as a valid redirect operator.

I could get around trying:

`Powershell -File "C:\myscript.ps1" 3>"C:\warninglog.txt" 2>"C:\errorlog.txt"`
 but I really want to write to the same file.

If I try to run:

```
Powershell -File "C:\myscript.ps1" 3>"C:\log.txt" 2>"C:\log.txt"
```

it seems the error stream (2) never gets written to log.txt because file is locked by the warning stream.

Is there a way to combine two (or more) output streams into a single stream and redirect the result to the same file ?

Answer (score 7):

The verbose, warning, and debug streams are merged into STDOUT when you run PowerShell scripts via

```
powershell -File "C:\myscript.ps1"
```

so you can't redirect them separately anymore. Only the error stream is different, since it seems to go to both STDOUT and STDERR, where it can be redirected by `1>` as well as `2>`.

Demonstration:

```
C:\>type test.ps1
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
Write-Output "Output message"
Write-Error "Error message"
Write-Verbose "Verbose message"
Write-Warning "Warning message"
Write-Debug "Debug message"

C:\>powershell -File .\test.ps1
Output message
C:\test.ps1 : Error message
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1

VERBOSE: Verbose message
WARNING: Warning message
DEBUG: Debug message

C:\>powershell -File .\test.ps1 2>nul 3>nul 4>nul 5>nul
Output message
VERBOSE: Verbose message
WARNING: Warning message
DEBUG: Debug message

C:\>powershell -File .\test.ps1 1>nul

C:\>_
```

If you want to redirect the verbose, warning, or debug stream separately you must use `-Command` instead of `-File` and do the redirection within PowerShell:

```
C:\>powershell -Command ".\test.ps1 2>$null 3>$null 5>$null"
Output message
VERBOSE: Verbose message
```

However, while in [CMD](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx) you can redirect any handle to any other handle (`3>&2`, `1>&5`, ...), [PowerShell redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) only supports redirection to either a file (`3>C:\out.txt`) or the success output stream (`3>&1`). Trying to redirect to any other stream will throw an error:

```
C:\>powershell -Command ".\test.ps1 2>out.txt 3>&2"
At line:1 char:22
+ .\test.ps1 2>out.txt 3>&2
+                      ~~~~
The '3>&2' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

as will redirecting different streams to the same file:

```
C:\>powershell -Command ".\test.ps1 2>out.txt 3>>out.txt"
out-file : The process cannot access the file 'C:\out.txt' because it is being
used by another process.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\test.ps1 2>out.txt 3>>out.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

If merging warning and success output is an option for you, you could do something like this:

```
powershell -Command ".\test.ps1 >out.txt 3>&1 2>error.log"
```

or like this:

```
powershell -Command ".\test.ps1 >out.txt 3>&1 2>&1"
```

or (redirecting all streams) like this:

```
powershell -Command ".\test.ps1 *>out.txt"
```

Otherwise the only option I see is to redirect to different files:

```
powershell -Command ".\test.ps1 3>warning.log 2>error.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the error and warning stream to the output stream separately so instead of doing this

```
  3>&2>&1
```

you should be doing this

```
  3>&1 2>&1
```

Adapted from [Understanding streams](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell.aspx)

```
function Write-Messages
{
    Write-Host "Host message"
    Write-Output "Output message"
    Write-Verbose "Verbose message"
    Write-Warning "Warning message"
    Write-Error "Error message"
    Write-Debug "Debug message"
}

$DebugPreference = "Continue"
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

Write-Messages 3>&1 2>&1 > $env:TEMP\test.txt
```

Applied to your example, this would become

```
Powershell -File "C:\myscript.ps1" 3>&1 2>&1> "C:\log.txt"
```

or you can redirect all streams to your file

```
Powershell -File "C:\myscript.ps1" *> "C:\log.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say capture the output stream into a variable and capture other streams into a different variable then you can do this using sub expressions:

```
$errorOutput = $( $output = & $command $arguments ) 2>&1
```

This is from an excellent article by [Simon Wahlin](https://blog.simonw.se/programmatically-capture-verbose-output-in-a-powershell-variable/)