# Redirect all output streams except the success stream to a file

Tags: powershell, redirect

I want to **redirect all PowerShell cmdlet output except stream 1 (success) to a file. How can I achieve that?** I know how to achieve to redirect individual stream, and I know how to merge it to standard output, but I don't want to mess standard output. I just want to capture  streams 2,3 4 and (optionally) 5 into a single file. I am using Windows platform.

As example, I used these commands:

```
@('c:\temp\', 'c:\temp2\') | % {Get-ChildItem $_}
```

I do have c:\temp folder with some files inside, and I do not have c:\temp2 folder. So **my expected output in file is to get only an error about missing folder temp2.**

I tried assigning value to a variable, but it did not help. Normal assigning is not generating the output, but once redirected output appears.

```
($Files = @('c:\temp\', 'c:\temp2\') | % {Get-ChildItem $_}) *>err.txt
```

Without redirection, I see only error that c:\temp2 is not existing. But once redirected, list of files from C:\temp appears in err.txt. And, it appears at the end of file. Furthermore, assignment to `$Files` in ISE environment is not happening!? In other hosts, assignment works fine, but redirect is also adding files to output.

If I try to redirect as `3>err.txt 2>err.txt` it fails with: *The process cannot access the file err.txt because it is being used by another process.*

Merging to any other stream except 1, is not supported. This attempt `3>&2 2>err.txt` gives the error: *The '3>&2' operator is reserved for future use.*

I was able to do something with `Start-Transcript`, but that creates additional text, and its flooding the output file with unnecessary text.

I was reading following articles, but I did not find proper answer

- [about_redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)
- [Understanding Streams, Redirection, and Write-Host in PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/)
- [Stack Overflow question: Redirect two or more Powershell streams other than output stream to the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906329/redirect-two-or-more-powershell-streams-other-than-output-stream-to-the-same-fil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **pragmatic workaround** is to use the common **`-ov` (`-OutVariable`)** parameter, which enables **collecting a cmdlet's success output in a *variable*, independently of how/whether the success stream is redirected**:

```
'c:\temp\', 'c:\temp2\' | % { Get-ChildItem $_ } -ov Files 1>$null *>err.txt
# Get-ChildItem success output is now stored in $Files
```

- `1>$null` suppresses the success stream
- `*>err.txt` redirects the remaining streams to file `err.txt`
- Note how `Files` rather than `$Files` is passed to `-ov`, because you must pass the *name* of the variable, not its value.

A caveat is that the variable specified for `-ov` receives the *entire* output and stores it in memory, which can be problematic with large output sets.

Also, as of PSv5.1, note that the output variable is invariably a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instance, even if only a single item was received.
This [may change in v6](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3154).

---

As an aside, a more efficient reformulation of your command is:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\, c:\temp2\ -ov Files 1>$null *>err.txt
```