# How to separate warning message from stdout/result in powershell redirection?

Tags: powershell, cmd, warnings, stdout, batch-processing

I'm trying to write a simple test script in PowerShell to [separate warning message from stdout/result](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/297055/capture-warning-verbose-debug-and-host-output-via-alternate-streams) in order to get two separate text files, one for warnings and one for standard results in [PowerShell Redirection](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html).

Here is my simple `output.ps1` script:

```
Write-Output "This is result"
Write-Warning "This is warning"
```

I'm trying to run `output.ps1` using a .bat file using below command:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& '%~dp0output.ps1'" 3>warning.txt >results.txt
pause
```

But my problem is `warning.txt` is completely empty, while both – warning and result – are written to `results.txt`.

```
This is result
WARNING: This is warning
```

What I am missing in `PowerShell.exe -Command "& '%~dp0output.ps1'" 3>warning.txt >results.txt` to separate warnings and errors into two files?

---

**Edit:** Modified to see standard error, `2>` is working.

Even if I redirect standard error to separate file using `2>error.txt` by using

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& '%~dp0output.ps1'" 2>error.txt 3>warning.txt >results.txt
```

and if I modify `output.ps1` to generate an error in the following manner

```
Write-Output "This is result"
Write-Warning "This is warning""
This will generate error because this is not a ps command.
```

it will generate the error as expected to a file `error.txt` with `results.txt` where `results.txt` is the combination of warning and stdout/result. `warning.txt` is still empty. I still can't figure out why PowerShell warnings are not filtered and redirected properly to a separate file.

**error.txt:**

```
this : The term 'this' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\output.ps1:3 char:1
+ This will generate error because this is not a ps command.
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (this:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**results.txt:**

```
This is result
WARNING: This is warning
```

I'm using Windows 10 and PowerShell Version 5.1.14393.1358.

Comment: What about `2>warning.txt` ?

Comment: powershell/cmd cant redirect warnings may be ? errors it can redirect using 2> .. but 3> will generate a blank output

Comment: As far as I know, cmd has only an error and a standard stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real problem, in the below example, is, When you use `powershell.exe` to execute a ps1 file **verbose**, **warning**, and **debug** streams are merged into STDOUT) -**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914113/3107413)**. (---resulting a blank `warning.txt`)

```
    PowerShell.exe -Command "& '%~dp0output.ps1'" 3>warning.txt >results.txt
```

To circumvent this limitation in `powershell.exe`,  there is a workaround for above example using extra intermediate ps1 file. You can use two powershell files and a bat file and get three separate files for `error/warning/results`.  (`2>error.txt 3>warning.txt >results.txt`)

Have the same content for `output.ps1` with below content.

```
Write-Output "This is result"
Write-Warning "This is warning""
This will generate error because this is not a ps command.
```

Then create another powershell file. (I will call it `newout.ps1`) and `newout.ps1` can run `output.ps1` with below content.

```
.\output.ps1 2>error.txt 3>warning.txt >results.txt
```

Finally your bat file can run `newout.ps1`1 instead of `output.ps1` in this manner.

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& '%~dp0newout.ps1'"
```

Which gives you three separate files with desired results.